# I need a getScale(map) method to get the scale value in Google maps api v3?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am using Google maps api v3.

It is currently possible to display a scale control, but there is no way to access the scale value from code.

I'd like a getScale(map) method to get the scale value,it should return meters/pixel values for the current zoom level.

Does any one know how to finish this method?

Thanks in advance....

Comment: have you seen this google employee answer? -> https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-maps-js-api-v3/hDRO4oHVSeM